# Is it possible to read a text file without using arrays? C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *f;

    char *chPtr = malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
/////////////////
    f=fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if(!f)
        return 1;
    while (fgets(*chPtr,1000,f)!=NULL) {
        printf("%c", *chPtr);
    }
    fclose(f);

    printf("\n%c", *(chPtr+4));
    return 0;
}
```

Our teacher said don't use [] 'brackets' so I'm assuming it's up to malloc, but couldn't make it work?

Comment: `fgets(chPtr,1000,f)`

Comment: You know, a `char` is never more nor less than exactly one `char` big.

Comment: Only prints the first letter of the line, any ideas to print the whole text file without using arrays

Comment: Well, you can read a character at a time using `fgetc()`, but if you use `fgets()` you're reading into an array object. There's a difference between "don't use arrays" (as suggested by your title) and "don't use `[]`" (as suggested by the body of your question). What *exactly* is your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this `fgets(*chPtr,1000,f)` with this `fgets(chPtr,1000,f)` and (as @MattMcnabb mentionned)`printf("%c", *chPtr)` with `printf("%s", chPtr)`

Comment: Well, that would only print the first letter of the line. So I'm gonna have to start using array to solve the problem, but that is not allowed. Any ideas?

Comment: also replace `printf("%c", *chPtr)` with `printf("%s", chPtr);`

Comment: It  works, Just for learning purpose, how did remove asterisks prints the whole line, I thought it would print the actual address if I leave it off.

Comment: let's suppose we have the string "abc" , and 4 memory addresses 0x1 0x2 0x3 0x4 , since the string is stored contiguously in memory we will find : at address 0x1 : 'a' at 0x2 'b' at 0x3 : 'c' and at 0x4 : '\0' the pointer you allocated points to address 0x1(just for the sake of explaining it usually is a much larger number ) so when you dereference it it will print the content of that address ('a') to understand print the content of the following address `printf("%s" , *(chPtr + 1))` and you'll see the following character

Comment: but when you do `printf("%s" , chPtr)` you give to `printf` a pointer to char no a value to print so `printf` follows that pointer and print the content of every address until that content is equal to `\0`